# How to delay response on user message with sms hooks?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My goal is to answer on user message with some delay - 1-5 minutes.
But in docs i don't see any ability to set the timeout.
Here is my code:

```
app.post('/sms', async (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  const msg = req.body.Body;
  const toroMsg = await toroProcess(msg);
  twiml.message(toroMsg);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to delay the response to a message within Twilio when [responding with TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml).

Instead you need to control the delay in your application, and [use the Twilio REST API to send the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) later.

It looks like you are using Express and Node in your question. The simplest way to do this would be to use a `setTimeout` like this:

```
const twilioClient = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

app.post('/sms', async (req, res) => {
  const msg = req.body.Body;
  const toroMsg = await toroProcess(msg);
  setTimeout(() => {
    twilioClient.messages.create({
      to: req.body.From,
      from: req.body.To,
      body: toroMsg
    })
  }, 60 * 1000)
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

Since this relies on the currently running process, you probably want to use something a bit more resilient that won't lose the messages if the process is restarted or crashes. Something like [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) or [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#readme).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: thank you, in your example you're going to send two messages to user, `res.end(twiml.toString());` as webhook responce, and second one in the setTimeout. Is there a way to skip that?

Comment: I'm actually returning empty TwiML in the initial response, which will give Twilio an initial response that just says "do nothing". Then the message is sent in the timeout.

Comment: Hi @philnash, I see you use different methods to send these two messages, where in setTimeout you use API, and the other using twiml, do you have any concern there? what is the difference ?

Thanks

Comment: @Windo when you respond with TwiML, Twilio will react to the response and carry out the instructions in the TwiML immediately. In this case, the question was about delaying a response. You could delay the response to the request, but Twilio will time out after 15 seconds. So it's best to use the REST API to respond in this case. In the code, I still respond with TwiML, but it's an empty `<Response/>` so it doesn't do anything. There isn't really a difference between sending a message in response with the API or TwiML, it is down to your preference or use case.

Comment: I see, so it is because of 15s timeout. if the user replies to that REST API message, will it still be in the same session? thanks a lot.

Comment: [Session cookies for Twilio messages last 4 hours](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-), so as long as they respond within that time, then yes. Note also that you can't respond to a specific message in SMS, messages are just sent and received chronologically.